# Why i cannot quit my node-webkit app

Tags: node-webkit

i'm building a node-webkit application i have made a link to quit

```
<span onClick="func App.quit()" title="Close">X</span>
```

but when i click it it says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What i am doing wrong here?

i do not understand why i am getting this error

i did added

```
var gui = require('nw.gui')
gui.quit()
</script>
```

i have to say in my packjage.js i open a url so all the javascripts are loaded from that url those javascript are not local on my device

Answer (score 4):

1. The quit API is **gui.App.quit()** but not **gui.quit()**.
2. Node-Webkit has 2 JS context, so if you use **<script>** tag to load JS from remote site, it will run in browser's JS context, as we know, **require** works in Node.js context. Read [this page](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts) to get more info.

Comment: i got it fixed with window.close now that is working fine
However when i do window.minimize(); it give me the error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'minimize' Any idea why?

Comment: Kai is right.Be careful, there are 2 window in node-webkit, the first one is browser's window object, the second one is node-webkit's native  window object.Read [Native UI API](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Native-UI-API-Manual) and [Native-UI's Window API](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window)

Answer (score 0):

as tinyproxy already mentioned, use `require('nw.gui').App` to manage application lifecycle. to minimize window and other window operation as well as listening to `window`-related events, use `require('nw.gui').Window.get()` as described here: [node-webkit Window](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window). For example, to minimize current window:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.minimize();
```